# Creation of.so of files

Tags: linux, unix, compilation, solaris

There is a set with - files with extension.с: avl_tree.c, buf_read.c, db_prep.c, file_process.c, global_header.c, traverser.c. Used include files are in folder/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/include except for jni.h, and libraries are in folder/usr/gcc/4.4/bin/lib. How from them to create.so the file (if it is possible specify all options in this command)? It me interests in communication by creation of native of methods by means of JNI.

Answer (score 1):

You really should read the documentation of GCC. Notably [invoking GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC). The [program library howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) is also relevant.

Very often, some builder is used to drive the build. [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is often used and has a good tutorial documentation. If your `Makefile`-s are complex, you may also want to use [GNU remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug them (`remake` is a debugging variant for `make`).

You usually want to compile each individual C source file into [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) because [shared objects](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) have PIC code. You can use

```
 gcc -Wall -fPIC -o foo.pic.o foo.c
```

to compile a C source `foo.c` into a position independent object file `foo.pic.o` and you may need some other compiler options (e.g. `-I` to add include directories, or `-D` to define some preprocessor symbols, `-g` for debugging, and `-O` for optimizing).

<sup>I strongly suggest to enable almost all warnings with `-Wall` (and to improve your code till no warnings are given; this will improve a little bit your code's quality).</sup>

Then you have to link all these `*.pic.o` files together into a shared object with

```
 gcc -shared *.pic.o -o foo.so
```

You can link some shared libraries into a shared object.

You may want to read [Levine's book on linkers and loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Of course if you use GNU `make` you'll have rules in your `Makefile` for all this.

You could use [GNU libtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Libtool) also.

Maybe [dlopen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) could interest you.

Comment: Why the option - Wall is necessary?

Comment: The option `-Wall` gives you warnings from the compiler, and the warnings usually catch easy mistakes. You can find on stackoverflow a lot of "stupid" questions which would have been caught with `-Wall`

Answer (score 0):

The question should probably give more information.

Most sets of sources have a Makefile, configure script or some other item to set up to make the output (the .so library you want).

gcc -dynamic -o file.so file.c

will create an so file from one of the source files, but you probably want a single so from all of them.

Comment: I would suggest `gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC file.c -o file.so`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why the option - Wall is necessary?