# Compile generate shared object files in ubuntu

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries

```
I want to get the shared object file(.so) by compiling
```

https://github.com/lucasjones/cpuminer-multi

> I used below commands, which generates a couple of .O files.

```
/autogen.sh 

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Downloads

make
```

> Could you help me to generate .so files? I want to use this files in a
>   couple of different platforms like Android, Ubuntu.

Comment: Given the recent bitcoin crash (december 2017), it might be *too late* to consider mining them for profit.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch its ok. I just wanted to try it for my learning purposes. Could you help me to create .so files, so that I could run it on android?

Comment: My answer contains several references to help you. I can't help more (don't have time to repeat what I have referenced).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared objects should, in practice, contain [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (PIC). See Drepper's [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900917/841108) answer. Simple build instructions for [shared libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12995506/841108) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26672678/841108).

In your [cpuminer-multi](https://github.com/lucasjones/cpuminer-multi) repository, there are some assembler files, e.g. [`aesb-x64.S`](https://github.com/lucasjones/cpuminer-multi/blob/master/aesb-x64.S) ..... So you need at least to check that the assembler code  inside them is PIC (or to patch these files to make them PIC).

> Could you help me to generate .so files? I want to use this files in a couple of different platforms

This might not work, since the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) (e.g. of common or standard libraries) could be slightly different. I would recommend a different build for each platform.

> ```
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Downloads
> ```

This looks strange (and smells bad). Read more about [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf). The `--prefix` relates to *installation* subdirectories, not to the build tree. I would recommend `--prefix=$HOME/soft/`  then adding `$HOME/soft/bin/` to your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).